# How to disable android keyboard and only show kivy keyboard?

Tags: android, kivy, keyboard

Kivy onscreen keyboard works perfect on laptop(As you can see [here](https://youtu.be/E4uJNuJ54VA)), but when I package the code I encounter 2 problems. Which are:

1.Both Android keyboard and kivy keyboard pops up. How can I disable Android keyboard only?
2.I am able to disable kivy keyboard, however android keyboard covers some of my widgets. How can I customize the android keyboard i.e change its color, size and position etc.

I tried using `window.softinput` but it didn't really change the android keyboard position. The Android keyboard always appears from the bottom. I also tried disabling android keyboard but to no avail.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','keyboard_mode', 'dock')
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.keyboard_anim_args = {'d':.2,'t':'in_out_expo'}
Window.softinput_mode = 'below_target'

class CustomTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CustomTextInput,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setup_keyboard()

    def setup_keyboard(self):
        kb = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_close, self)
        if kb.widget:
            #kb.widget.background_color = (0,0,1,1)
            #kb.widget.background = 'bg.png'
            kb.widget.key_background_color = (1,1,0,1)
            kb.widget.font_size = 25
            kb.widget.layout = 'numeric.json'

    def _keyboard_close(self):
        pass

class StartApp(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    StartApp:
        name: 'start'

<StartApp>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        CustomTextInput:
            #keyboard_mode: 'managed'
        Button:
            text: 'press me'
        Widget:
```

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src/android/_android.pyx#L233

have you tried this?

Comment: I don't know how to apply the above

Answer (score 0):

Just in text properties add (`keyboard=False`).

***Note:*** I found the keyboard property in the error log as shown in the below screenshot. but, I couldn't find it in kivy documentation even though in the latest version.

**My Screenshot**

[image: solution]